# Build Shared Library File from String of Code?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

Suppose I have a C++ code excerpt literal saved in a `std::string` variable, as such:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string code = "";
    code += "#include <iostream>\n";
    code += "\n";
    code += "int test()\n";
    code += "{\n";
    code += "   std::cout << \"test\";\n";
    code += "\n";
    code += "   return 0;\n";
    code += "}\n";

    // Save "code" to DLL...

    return 0;
}
```

Where the `code` local variable stores a C++ function called `test()` that just prints `test` to the console.

Is it possible to now compile the code stored in the `code` string variable into a shared library DLL file and save it?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, on a machine that has a compiler toolchain installed.

Comment: Suppose I was running this code inside of Visual Studio. What would be the command to achieve this in the VS Command Prompt?

Comment: Not sure if pipes work in cmd, but if they do, you can just pass the output of this code to the C++ compiler (with some flags) to generate the dll.